# Laravel Order results by conditional counting Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

I've a **posts** table with following structure

| id | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Post A | Description A |
| 2 | Post B | Description B |

**reactions** table with following structure:

| id | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Like | *http://like_url* |
| 2 | Dislike | *http://dislike_url* |

And **post_reactions** *pivot table* with following structure

| post_id | user_id | reaction_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

---

How can I achieve **posts** table result **OrderBy** Max Count of ReactionID?

For e.g.

- By ordering with *reactionId = 1*, the result should be:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Post A',
    description: 'Description A'
    reaction_count: 2         // count of reactionId=1 is maximum here
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Post B',
    description: 'Description B'
    reaction_count: 1         
  } 
]
```

- By ordering with *reactionId = 2*, the result should be:

```
[
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Post B',
    description: 'Description B'
    reaction_count: 1      // count of reactionId=2 is maximum here 
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Post A',
    description: 'Description A'
    reaction_count: 2         
  },
]
```

---

What I'd tried is:

```
// Post Model
public function reactions(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Reaction::class)->withPivot('user_id');
    }

// Controller
Post:: select(array
    ('*', \DB::raw('(SELECT count(*)
    FROM post_reactions 
    WHERE post_reactions.reaction_id ='. $reactionId.') as reaction_counts'))

   );
    $query->orderBy('reaction_counts', 'desc');
```

***Note**: I need all the post sorted by the count of the reactions given reaction_id*

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Yes, but no luck. I'm editing the post again to add codes what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models:

```
$posts = Post::withCount('reactions')->orderBy('reactions_count')->get();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    //display reactions count
    echo $post->reactions_count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've to aware of 2 things — First, I've to show all reactions including unmatched reactionId (meaning, it should not be filtered by reactionId). Second, I've to Order records by reaction_count within the Query instead of collection.